# How to setup an alias for local facing interface

Tags: networking

I'm trying to set an alias for an interface facing local network, but when i try to bring it up I receive this error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1:0.
```

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces
    # Loopback device:
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

```
# device: eth0
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   X.X.X.X
  broadcast X.X.X.X
  netmask   255.255.255.0
  gateway   X.X.X.1

# device: eth1
auto  eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address   10.0.0.1
  netmask   255.255.252.0

# device: eth1:0
auto  eth1:0
iface eth1:0 inet static
  address   10.0.0.2
  netmask   255.255.252.0

# default route to access subnet
up route add -net X.X.X.X netmask 255.255.255.0 gw X.X.X.1 eth0
```

Comment: From my reading, it appears this is a problem with having multiple network routes, but I wan't able to get this working either. Best I've been able to manage is to have the vip show up under the physical adapter when running `ip addr`. The ip does work though.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question when possible (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 1):

The "file" that "already exists" is **the default route** (gateway).

`ifup` will fail because it will try to add a default route that already exists for the base adapter. As @DanatheSane indicated in the comments, you can ignore this -- the alias works nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You should really remove the last line, as tries to do the exact same work as is done in the `eth0` section:

- The `gateway` setting means you get it as the (default) gateway.
- The `netmask` (with `address`) adds a route for the local network, telling your machine how to send packets that can be reach on the local area network.

In summary: the last line is redundant.